# how to close selenium hub/grid from command prompt

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I start Selenium hub to start Selenium Grid from command prompt on port 4444.
Now I start Selenium RC from other command prompt.

It shows me error message that "Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is..."

Now I am not able to start Selenium RC. Please help me how to close /shutdown hub from command prompt.

Answer (score 14):

http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

is the command to close the opened selenium session. If the session is opened using batch file please remove the '@pause' command if its is used. This is useful when we are trying to stop and start the server during or in between test case execution.

Or

"Ctrl + C" is the best option.

Comment: can you please link to the documentation where you found the `shutDownSeleniumServer` cmd ? I’m lost

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you can shut it down

http://host-server:port/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

Answer (score 8):

The URL command shutDownSeleniumServer is no longer supported as of Selenium 3.0.

[This github issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2852) suggests that the servlet that manages the lifecycle is still available, but accessible through a different URL:

`http://{hubhost}:{hubport}/lifecycle-manager/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown`

If the server is running as a node, the servlet has to be enabled at runtime:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -role node -servlet org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet`

And the shutdown URL for a node is:

`http://{nodehost}:{nodeport}/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown`

Answer (score 3):

You only need to hit this link http://localhost:4444/lifecycle-manager?action=shutdown

Answer (score 2):

I am trying this
 we can also use our web browser to stop the server.

you can try following URL to shut down the server.
http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to register your RC's with the Selenium Hub. Each RC needs to register on a different port (I think). You can use ant to boot the RC on a specific port

`ant -Dport=5556 launch-remote-control`

I found running the demos that come with Grid really helpful:

http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/run_the_demo.html

hth

Answer (score 1):

what is safer solution?

```
kill -p "$SELENIUM_PID"
```

or

```
wget http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
```

i am making a init.d script for headless selenium and this is important step.

Comment: Did you get a comment regarding which is safer?

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do from a browser (e.g. http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDown), but you can also call that url with curl if you need command line access.

Answer (score 0):

You can to press "ctrl"+"C" in command window, (where hub or RC is running) and to stop execution of batch file

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question of how do you close selenium hub from the command prompt, you can try this from the selenium-grid folder:
(from documentation)
rake all:restart
rake all:stop

Or for specific ports:
rake all:restart PORTS=5000-5010
rake all:stop PORTS=5000-5010

Answer (score 0):

This (http://localhost:4444/lifecycle-manager?action=shutdown) link is removed under version 3.0. 
In windows, you must stop Java service.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. It is not a link to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is running in a command prompt you can use "taskkill" to stop all cmd.exe instances.
What I do for selenium grid 4 is start the hub and nodes with specific names via a batch script. And then to stop them I use taskkill to kill the cmd.exe processes with the specified names. I know this isn't the documented way of doing it but it works.
Example:

```
start "SeleniumHub" cmd /c java -jar selenium-server-4.5.0.jar hub
```

This starts a cmd.exe process with a title of SeleniumHub that we can later reference.

To stop the hub:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq  SeleniumHub" /T
```

where /f is force. /fi is filter based on the window title that equals Seleniumhub and /t is to kill all child processes
hope this helps someone.